how to get rid of discord.Object(is="My guild id") without breaking everything in discord.py
I create a discord bot in slash but with each command I have to specify the server id, which is very annoying for everything that is inter-server compatibility (if I do not specify the object guild=discord.Object(id=" Guild id here") the command is not recognized as a slash in the server), here is the code:
main.py:
import os;os.system("cls||clear")
import discord, json
from utils import Invite, EmbedCreator, OPEN_TICKET
from discord import app_commands, Object
with open("config.json", "+r") as file: config = json.load(file)
intents = discord.Intents.all();client = discord.Client(intents=intents);tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client);TOKEN = config["TOKEN"];SERVER_ID = config["SERVER_ID"]
def is_admin(interaction): member = interaction.guild.get_member(interaction.user.id);return member.guild_permissions.administrator if member else False

@client.event
async def on_ready(): await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))

@tree.command(name="invite", description=f"Avoir le lien pour inviter le bot !", guild=Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def _(interaction):
    try: await interaction.response.send_message(view=Invite(f"[En cliquant ici](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client.user.id}&scope=applications.commands)"))
    except Exception as e: await interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title="ERREUR INTERNE",description=str(e),color=discord.Color.red()))

@tree.command(name="ping",description="Voir le Ping du bot !", guild=Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def _(interaction):embed = discord.Embed(title="Ping", description=f"╰┈➤ `{round(client.latency*1000)}`ms ️", color=discord.Color.green());embed.set_footer(text="Made by ItsPyDevs");await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

@tree.command(name="embed", description="Crée un Embed selont votre input !", guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def _(interaction):await interaction.response.send_modal(EmbedCreator())

@tree.command(name='clear', description='Clear a specified number of messages in the channel.', guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def _(interaction, amount: int):
    if not is_admin(interaction): interaction.response.send_message("You do not have permission to use this command.");return;await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)

@tree.command(name="ticket", description="Crée un Ticket selont votre input !", guild=Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def _(interaction): 
    if is_admin: await interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title="Ouvrir un ticket", description="Click sur le bouton ci dessous pour ouvrir un ticket !", color=discord.Color.dark_blue()), view=OPEN_TICKET())
    else: interaction.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title="ERREUR INTERNE",description="Vous n'avez pas les permissions suffisantes pour crée cette interaction !",color=discord.Color))

client.run(TOKEN)

utils.py:
import discord

class Invite(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, inv=str):super().__init__();self.inv = inv
    @discord.ui.button(label="Invite moi !", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger,emoji="<:1_pepefuckyou:1223613141057929246>")
    async def invitebutton(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button): await interaction.response.send_message(self.inv, ephemeral=True)

class EmbedCreator(discord.ui.Modal, title='Créateur d\'embed !'):
    titre = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Titre de l\'embed', required=True)
    description = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Description de l\'embed', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, required=True)
    color = discord.ui.TextInput(label='couleur de l\'embed en RGB (0 0 0)', required=False)
    field1 = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Nom du champ 1', required=False, style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph)
    field1_value = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Valeur du champ 1', required=False, style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph)
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=self.titre.value, description=self.description.value)
        if self.field1.value and self.field1_value.value: embed.add_field(name=self.field1, value=self.field1_value, inline=False)
        if self.color and self.color.value:
            color_values = self.color.value.split()
            if len(color_values) == 3:
                try:r, g, b = map(int, color_values);embed.color = discord.Color.from_rgb(r, g, b)
                except ValueError:pass
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

class TICKET(discord.ui.Modal, title='Créateur de Ticket'):
    titre = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Titre du problème', required=True)
    description = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Description du Problème', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, required=True)
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        
        embed = discord.Embed(title=self.titre.value, description=self.description.value, color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0,0,255))
        existing_ticket = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name=f'ticket-{interaction.user.name}')
        if existing_ticket:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Vous ne pouvez créer qu'un seul ticket.", ephemeral=True)
            return
        ticket_channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket-{interaction.user.name}')
        deleted_ping = await ticket_channel.send(f"<@{interaction.user.id}>")
        await ticket_channel.send(embed=embed)
        await deleted_ping.delete()
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Ticket créé avec succès dans {ticket_channel.mention}', ephemeral=True)

class OPEN_TICKET(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @discord.ui.button(label="Ouvrir un ticket !", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary,emoji="")
    async def open_ticket(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button): 
        await interaction.response.send_modal(TICKET())

i have tried somethings like this but it fail:
for id in client.guild:
     @tree.command(name="test", guild=discord.Object(id=id))
     # rest of exemple command

Thank you for the help/responses to this post!

The problem is with the command tree syncing. Let me simplify the problem.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))

@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID))
async def guild_specific_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ...

@tree.command()
async def global_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    ...

In this case, only guild_specific_command would be synced because you specified to only sync commands with guild=discord.Object(id=SERVER_ID).
To fix this, sync it globally:
@client.event
async def on_ready():
     await tree.sync()

This should sync not only the server specific commands to the servers, but also the non-server specifc (global) commands to all servers.
